# Who actually created "Waste Not"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

While perusing gatherer today I came across the [15 special guest designed magic cards](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/designer-cards-magic-2015-2014-04-16-0) that came out in the M15 set. One card kind of stood out to me, [Waste Not](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383436). Whereas the other cards are attributed to each designer (eg. [Aggressive Mining](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383179) has Markus Persson, [Avarice Amulet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383186) has Penny Arcade etc.) in the flavour text, Waste Not has the following flavour text:

> *Designed by the Magic community*

**I am wondering how was Waste Not created, and why was it attributed to the Magic community instead of a specific person?**
If it was contest type thing where many  people submitted different card designs it seems odd that the winning design wouldn't have its designers name put onto the card.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My name is CJ Mlsna, and I submitted the rules text for the card that became Waste Not. Jennifer Clarke Wilkes had a different entry in YMTC 4.

When the card was released alongside the other guest-designed cards, I asked Ethan Fleischer why my name had been omitted. His answer was that since it had been voted on by the community, it should have the credit it did. I was able to submit some short answers to a survey they emailed me, which was [posted here](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/you-make-card-4-%E2%80%93-winning-mechanic-2013-05-28).

Comment: Welcome to the site! (a very late) Congrats on your card, I have seen it star in many interesting decks, including a modern one my roommate created that is doing fairly well at our LGS.

Answer (score 12):

The Magic community as a whole created Waste Not in an event know as "You Make the Card 4". (The first three You Make the Card cards were [Forgotten Ancient](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForgotten%20Ancient%5d), [Crucible of Worlds](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrucible%20of%20Worlds%5d), and [Vanish into Memory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVanish%20into%20Memory%5d).) The Magic website hosted a series of polls to determine the card's color, color, type, and so on. The final results page, including an overview of the voting rounds and results, can be found at http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/you-made-card-2013-09-30-0

Comment: Well, the specific designs (once black enchantment was chosen) were still community-submitted, right? The polls were ultimately just a top 8 single elimination bracket picking from 8 top designs that Wizards chose among the thousands of submissions. But they never attributed them, as far as I know - the [rules bracket article](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/you-make-card-4-%E2%80%93-rules-bracket-2015-09-15) just lists the contenders.

Comment: Neat, that final link is particularly interesting reading. One of [the losing designs](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/you-make-card-4-%E2%80%93-rules-bracket-2015-09-15) looks familiar. "At the beginning of your upkeep, choose one—You draw two cards and lose 2 life; or destroy target creature; or Cast a spell without paying its mana cost; or you lose the game. You can't choose the same mode twice". Seems like [Demonic Pact](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398433).

Comment: @Malco http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/original-spin-2015-08-17 - interestingly, when they printed Demonic Pact, MaRo *did* acknowledge the designer.

Comment: Wait, okay, look at the article you linked - the people who submitted the cards are credited there. Waste Not was submitted by Jennifer Clarke Wilkes. Should've seen that sooner, but kind of assumed it wasn't in there since you linked it!